# what's the best indexing for votes table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT qa.id,
       qa.subject,
       qa.category cat,
       qa.keywords tags,
       qa.body_html,
       qa.amount,
       qa.visibility,
       qa.date_time,
       COALESCE(u.reputation, 'N') reputation,
       COALESCE(CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname), 'unknown') name,
       COALESCE(u.avatar, 'anonymous.png') avatar,

  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
   FROM votes vv
   WHERE qa.id = vv.post_id
     AND 15 = vv.table_code) AS total_votes,

  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vt.total_viewed),0)
   FROM viewed_total vt
   WHERE qa.id = vt.post_id
     AND 15 = vt.table_code
   LIMIT 1) AS total_viewed
FROM qanda qa
LEFT JOIN users u ON qa.author_id = u.id
AND qa.visibility = 1
WHERE qa.type = 0
ORDER BY qa.date_time DESC
LIMIT 0,
      11;
```

And here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

See? the last row (`vv`) doesn't benefit any index. Also here are the current indexes on the `votes` table:

[image]

Anyway, what's your suggestion? What index do I need to make the performance more better?

Comment: does the table vote containes lot of data or lot of cocurrency  ? why don't you add PK on VOTE on column post_id then you have unique data and and index on post_id , you  can add index on post_id and table_code because your selecting ti in the where condition

Comment: As an aside, LIMIT 1 would appear to be redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move `qa.visibility = 1` from the `LEFT JOIN..ON` to the `WHERE`.  Once you have done that, have these indexes:

```
qanda:  INDEX(visibility, type, date_time)  -- date_time must be last
```

This will completely handle the `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` -- this may be the biggest boost in performance.

```
vv and vt:  INDEX(post_id, table_code) -- in either order
```

You seem to have `(post_id, table_code, user_id)`.  If that is unique, then promote it to be the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`; this will give an extra little boost.

I assume `users` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?

You don't need `LIMIT 1` on the `vt` subquery.

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Please take a look at your paragraph: *"You seem to have .."* ..! Yes exactly, so you mean I can remove `id` column? Honestly a table without `id` column is weird `:-)`, isn't it?

Comment: A table without a _primary key_ is weird.  Often a "natural PK" is better in various ways than an artificial `id`.  InnoDB, when looking up via a secondary index, gets the PK (`id`, at the leaf node of the secondary BTree), then does a second lookup via the PK.  By moving the index into the PK (if it is unique) lets the lookup take one step, not two.